I need to return data as strings inside a list not as lists inside another list
I'm relatively new to programming, I need to pull weekly data from GA4 to a google sheet but I'm failing to get the data appended properly as it being inserted as an object in google sheets, I kind of see where the problem is but struggling to resolve it.
Here's my code, as well as I see when I console log the data vs what I see in the google sheet.
function pullDataFromGA4() {
  // Set the Google Analytics 4 property ID.
  const propertyId = 'GA4_PROPERTY_ID';
  
  // Set the start date for the data pull (1 week ago)
  const startDate = new Date();
  startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 7);

  // Set the end date for the data pull (yesterday)
  const endDate = new Date();
  endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() - 1);

  // Set date format to YYYY-MM-DD
  const dateFormatter = Utilities.formatDate;

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  sheet.clear(); // Clear existing data
  
  const headers = ['Week', 'Session Default Channel Group', 'Total Users', 'New Users', 'Sessions'];
  sheet.appendRow(headers); // Add headers

  try {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      const weekStart = new Date(startDate);
      weekStart.setDate(startDate.getDate() + (7 * i));

      const weekEnd = new Date(startDate);
      weekEnd.setDate(startDate.getDate() + (7 * (i + 1)) - 1);

      const formattedStartDate = dateFormatter(weekStart, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      const formattedEndDate = dateFormatter(weekEnd, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');

      const dateRange = AnalyticsData.newDateRange();
      dateRange.startDate = formattedStartDate;
      dateRange.endDate = formattedEndDate;

      const dimensions = [];
      const metricsArray = [];

      const sessionDefaultChannelGroup = AnalyticsData.newDimension();
      sessionDefaultChannelGroup.name = 'sessionDefaultChannelGroup';
      dimensions.push(sessionDefaultChannelGroup);
      
      const totalUsers = AnalyticsData.newMetric();
      totalUsers.name = 'totalUsers';
      metricsArray.push(totalUsers);

      const newUsers = AnalyticsData.newMetric();
      newUsers.name = 'newUsers';
      metricsArray.push(newUsers);

      const sessions = AnalyticsData.newMetric();
      sessions.name = 'sessions';
      metricsArray.push(sessions);

      const request = AnalyticsData.newRunReportRequest();
      request.dimensions = dimensions;
      request.metrics = metricsArray;
      request.dateRanges = [dateRange];

      const response = AnalyticsData.Properties.runReport(request, 'properties/' + propertyId);
      
      const weekData = response.rows.map((row) => {
        const metricValues = row.metricValues.map(
            (metricValue) => metricValue.value);

        const dimensionValues = row.dimensionValues.map(
            (dimensionValue) => dimensionValue.value);

        return [formattedStartDate + ' - ' + formattedEndDate, ...dimensionValues, ...metricValues];
      });
      console.log(headers)
      console.log(weekData);
      sheet.appendRow(weekData);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Failed with error: %s', e.toString());
  }
}




SpreasheetApp.Sheet.appendRow parameter expects an array with the values for a single row, but weekData is an Array of Arrays.
Instead of SpreasheetApp.Sheet.appendRow, use SpreasheetApp.Range.setValues.
As you know, the values from weekData are always added to the second row, using two as the first parameter.
From
sheet.appendRow(weekData);

To
sheet.getRange(2,1,weekData.length, headers.length).setValues(weekData);

